# How to install LyX Enchant spell cheker?

Tags: lyx

My current LyX program does not check for misspelled words. Some posts suggest downloading Enchant spell checker files.

I have no idea as to how to what path to be used in order to configure.  Can anyone help?

Comment: This is an known bug for windows platforms. However, lyx's dev managed to solve it, by re-creating a new installer for the version 2.1.4. So, try to re-install LyX and see if spellchecker works smoothly

Comment: What OS are you on? Yorgos covered the Windows case. If you're on Ubuntu this is strange because it should just work out of the box, I believe.